# jQueryMobile, Phonegap and Device Token - iOS

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, device, token

I have my app working with JQueryMobile and PhoneGap... I can send Push Notifications without problems to the devices, but I don't know how associate an user account with a device token. I register the device token in the event:

```
didregisterforremotenotificationswithdevicetoken
```

and I save the device token in my database.

But the problem is that I have the user login account in a HTML page (with jQueryMobile)... and I don't know how can associate the user id of my login page in HTML with the device token that I have in my database...

Can anybody explain me how can I save the device token of the device and associate to the user id (for example, an email)??? I want to use it because I want to send a notification only to one user, not to everybody!!!

Thank you so much, and sorry for me English!