# Suggestion on how to link APN's device token to a registered user (through phonegap or UIWebView)

Tags: ios, cordova, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Similar question here: [jQueryMobile, Phonegap and Device Token - iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9022983/jquerymobile-phonegap-and-device-token-ios)

The scenario is, I have this PhoneGap web based application, and the native iOS help me registered the device on APN and I received the device token in my server database.

**Question 1:** How do you associate a registered user (through the UIWebView) to this device token using PhoneGap?

- What's in my mind now is to write a custom plugin and pass the device token along during user registration. Is there any better alternative?

**Question 2:** Since device_token can be changed from time to time, how should I re-link this user to this device_token?

- Perhaps whenever the user login, I do a window.plugins.*PluginName*.getDeviceToken and sync it?
- `{user_id:123, old_device_token: 'xxxx..', new_device_token: 'xxx...'}`?

Fyi, this application is built for an event and the client has requested people to people messaging on this mobile app. How do you push a *new message notification* to "John Doe" when he received a message from his friend? - Question is how to link "John Doe" to a specific device_token?

This could not be too iOS specific as this application has to be deployed on Android as well (C2DM).

Any help is welcomed!

**Edit: Possible solution?**

Restless research emerges this possible solution:

1. [Native] Application started - APN registration started and device_token is received
2. [Native] Store this device_token into local store (CoreData/SqlLite or Property Lists?) and send it to server to do device_token registration
3. [WebView] Whenever a user is login or signup, this device_token will be queried through PhoneGap, hashed and sent over to the server to do a sign in, comparison and link up.

Any unforeseen scenario is problematic?

**EDIT: Answer**

I have my complete working solution posted in the answer. Check it out here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9628592/534862

Comment: Did you make any progress on a plugin or something else that could pass to PhoneGap ?

Comment: Not yet. I'm still working on this project and once I get something I will post it here

Comment: Did you manage to make my solution work ?

Comment: Yes man, just got it work this evening after full day exploring it. I have it converted to Cordova and it works perfectly now. Accepted your answer. I will post my solution up later

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I finally made a plugin that seems to work

1 - Make sure your PhoneGap Xcode project has been updated for the iOS 4 SDK.

2 - Create a PushToken folder in your Plugins folder add the following PushToken.m and PushToken.h files to it and then drag the folder to the Plugin folder in XCode, using "Create groups for any added folders"

3 - Add the PushToken.js files to your www folder on disk, and add reference(s) to the .js files as tags in your html file(s)

4 - Add new entry with key PushToken and string value PushToken to Plugins in PhoneGap.plist

**PushToken.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <PhoneGap/PGPlugin.h>

@interface PushToken : PGPlugin{

    NSString* callbackID;  
}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* callbackID;

- (void) getToken:(NSMutableArray*)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary*)options;

@end
```

**PushToken.m**

```
#import "PushToken.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation PushToken

@synthesize callbackID;

-(void)getToken:(NSMutableArray*)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary*)options  {
    self.callbackID = [arguments pop];

    NSString *token = ((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).token;
    PluginResult* pluginResult = [PluginResult resultWithStatus:PGCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:[token stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    if(token.length != 0)
    {
        [self writeJavascript: [pluginResult toSuccessCallbackString:self.callbackID]];
    }else {    
        [self writeJavascript: [pluginResult toErrorCallbackString:self.callbackID]];
    }
}

@end
```

**PushToken.js**

```
var PushToken = {
    getToken: function(types, success, fail) {
        return PhoneGap.exec(success, fail, "PushToken", "getToken", types);
    }
};
```

**How to use**

```
PushToken.getToken(     
    ["getToken"] ,           
    function(token) {
        console.log("Token : "+token); 
    },
    function(error) {
        console.log("Error : \r\n"+error);      
    }
);
```

**AppDelegate.h**

```
@interface AppDelegate : PhoneGapDelegate {
    NSString* invokeString;
    NSString* token;
}

@property (copy)  NSString* invokeString;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString* token;
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{
    self.token = [[[[deviceToken description]
                         stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"<" withString: @""]
                        stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @">" withString: @""]
                       stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];

    NSLog(@"My token is: %@", self.token);
}
```

I made it work on PhoneGap 1.1

Hope this helps

Comment: Added answer as my next post ;)

Comment: so where's the plugins folder that's not the plugins folder in xcode?

Answer (score 5):

For the sake of completeness, this is my solution after using @TDeBailleul solution. Ported over to Cordova. (Tested on iOS only. After I have finished Android version I will post a plugin for this:

**Environment**

- Cordova 1.5.0 (Formerly PhoneGap)
- Xcode 4.3.1
- iOS 5.1
- Mac OS X 10.7.3
- Do not use Automatic Reference Counting (ARC) to avoid compilation error
- Go through [this freaking long tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12) to have your Push Notification certificate ready

**Working Flow**

1. [Native] Application started - APN registration started and device_token is received at server side
2. [Native] Application store the token in `AppDelegate`, and to get the token, use the `PushToken` in the following codes
3. [WebView] Whenever a user is login or signup, the token will be called through Cordova (formerly PhoneGap) plugin, hashed and being sent over to the server to do a sign in, matching and link up the user to a particular device.

So below is my complete working codes that do the native pulling of token. Server part is nothing but just linking accounts to devices. You should know how to do it through your favourite server side application.

**AppDelegate.h**

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject < UIApplicationDelegate, UIWebViewDelegate, CDVCommandDelegate > {
    ...
    NSString* token;
    ...
}
...
...
...
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString* token;
```

**AppDelegate.m**

**Note: I'm a Obj-C newbie and I have included my attempt to post token to my server as well. If you do not need the posting mechanism, retain the first 5 lines (til' `self.token = dt`) in the `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken`**

```
...

@synthesize token;

...

- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{    
...
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
    (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];

    return YES;
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
    NSLog(@"Did finish launching with device token %@", deviceToken);
    NSString *dt = [[deviceToken description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
    dt = [dt stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

    self.token = dt;

    NSString *dv = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
    NSString *dn = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemName];
    NSString *nick = [[UIDevice currentDevice] name];
    NSString *model = [[UIDevice currentDevice] model];
    NSString *uniqueIdentifier = [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier];

    NSMutableString *postData = [NSMutableString stringWithString: @"&deviceToken="];

    [postData appendString:dt];
    [postData appendFormat:@"&uniqueIdentifier=%@&application_uuid=5ade8400-e29c-41d4-a716-3641972a2ec6", uniqueIdentifier];
    [postData appendFormat:@"&source=ios&name=%@&model=%@&systemName=%@&systemVersion=%@", nick, model, dn, dv];

    NSString* escapedURLString = [postData stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    @try {
        NSData *postData = [escapedURLString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]
                                        initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"{YOUR URL TO POST TOKEN TO SERVER}"]
                                        cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval: 180];
        NSString *postLength = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"%d", [postData length]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];


        NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
        if (conn) {
            //??
        }else{
            //??
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"Exception %@", exception);
    }
}
...
```

**PushToken.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CORDOVA/CDVPlugin.h>

@interface PushToken : CDVPlugin {
    NSString* callbackID;
}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* callbackID;

- (void) getToken:(NSMutableArray*)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary*)options;

@end
```

**PushToken.m**

```
#import "PushToken.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation PushToken

@synthesize callbackID;

- (void)getToken:(NSMutableArray *)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary *)options {

    NSLog(@"Did called getToken");
    self.callbackID = [arguments pop];

    NSString *token = ((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).token;
    CDVPluginResult *pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:[token stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    if (token.length != 0) {
        [self writeJavascript: [pluginResult toSuccessCallbackString:self.callbackID]];
    }else{
        [self writeJavascript: [pluginResult toErrorCallbackString:self.callbackID]];
    }
}

@end
```

**PushToken.js**

```
var PushToken = {
    /**
    * Get token from the device
    * @param {array} types - By default is ['getToken']
    * @param {function} success Success callback, with token
    * @param {function} fail Failure callback, with null
    */
    getToken: function(types, success, fail) {
        return Cordova.exec(success, fail, "PushToken", "getToken", types);
    },

    /**
    * For the sake of iOS, we need an install function
    */
    install: function() {
        window.plugins = window.plugins || {};
        window.plugins.PushToken = PushToken;
    }
};

/**
* For the rest of the devices
*/
window.plugins = window.plugins || {};
window.plugins.PushToken = PushToken;
```

**Usage**

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
    if (typeof PushToken == 'object') {
        PushToken.install();
    }

    PushToken.getToken(['getToken'], function(token) {
        callback(token);
    }, function() {
        callback(null);
    });
});
```

And you should be able to get your token from your Javascript side ;)

Have fun!

Cheers

Answer (score 5):

The previous answers are really great ways to solve this problem and they do it in a very formal fashion. However, if you want a quick and dirty method of solving the problem, you can simply do this:

**at the bottom of didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken add**

```
NSString* jsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"var deviceToken = \"%@\";", deviceToken];
[self.viewController.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];
```

**In your javascript**

```
deviceId = (typeof deviceToken !== "undefined") ? deviceToken : null;
```

Comment: Where does this go? There are multiple instances of `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken`.