# Generate Device token ID in phonegap from iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova

How can I generate a `DeviceId` in `phonegap`? I need help with `iOS` code that needs to add in my `phonegap` project to communicate with `APNS` to get back a `DeviceId`

Comment: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_device_device.md.html#device.uuid  is this what you want?

Comment: Thanks for your response - this to generate device uuid however i am working registration generated by APNS ie apple cloud to generate id for particular project id and device for push notification

Comment: I think, what you are looking for is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9407050/suggestion-on-how-to-link-apns-device-token-to-a-registered-user-through-phone)